# Get the next object in list after the object with current ID

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I know the title is confusing so I will try my best to explain here...

I have

```
class T{
   int id;
   string value;
}


List<T> objs;
```

in my code when I retrieve the initial list I grab the first id with

```
int currentID = objs.FirstOrDefault().id;
```

now I need to grab next. not knowing the current position of where I am how can I grab the next item id...

```
 objs.select(x => x.id)
        .where(//you are the object that exists after the one with currentID);
```

Comment: The object that exists after the first one would just be the second one (`objs[1]`), correct?  Or am I missing some detail?  Are you saying you want the fist object that has a _different_ id?

Comment: @DStanley the id's can be random, and in any order, they are internally sorted on a different property then random ones are removed based on conditions leaving me with a list of say id's (1,57,12,417,3)

Comment: So your "first" id is 1 and your "next" id is 57? Or 3?

Comment: @DStanley yes, each object within the collection has a priority stored within it. the ID is just the ID of the object for database reference (unique identifier) the priority is what is sorted on,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get next element after some element then you can use `SkipWhile()` and  `Skip()` methods like that:

```
objs.SkipWhile(x => x.id == currentID).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: "x => x.id" won't necessarily resolve to a boolean. You could cast, but that may not give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You are just indexing, so use `ElementAt`:

```
int i = 0; //current position
int currentID = objs.ElementAt(i).id;
i++;
```

Execute in a loop to get the next one, etc.

If you actually just want to iterate through all elements, just use a `foreach`:

```
foreach (T obj in objs)
{
   int currentID = obj.id;
}
```

Finally, you could use `GetEnumerator` and utilize the `MoveNext` function along with the `Current` property. This is basically using a `foreach` but controlling the iteration yourself.